# Can you count the number of retries in an Clojure STM transaction with an atom?

Tags: clojure, transactions, stm

Can you count the number of retries in an Clojure STM transaction with an atom? I tried it like below and it seems to work:

```
(def annotatedCounter (agent 0))
(def finishedCounter (agent 0))
(def annotatedSentences (ref {}))
(def corroboratedSentences (ref {}))
(def retryCounter (atom 0))

;; ...

(defn upvote [id]
  (dosync
    (if (contains? @annotatedSentences id)
      (alter annotatedSentences update-in [id :counter] inc)))

  (dosync
    (if (contains? @annotatedSentences id)
      (do
        (if (> (get-in @annotatedSentences [id :counter]) 5)
          (do
            (swap! retryCounter inc)
            (alter corroboratedSentences conj {id (get @annotatedSentences id)})
            (alter annotatedSentences dissoc annotatedSentences id)
            (send annotatedCounter dec)
            (send finishedCounter inc)))))))
```

I added the retryCounter seen above inside the longer of the transactions, to count the total number of transactions. I know agents would only get sent an inc function once in a transaction, regardless of retries, but does this work, to count the number of transactions with an atom?

Comment: Sure, non-transactional side effects like modifying an atom will leak out of your transaction, as you intend. But it seems like a weird thing to do: why do you care how many retries there have been?

Comment: Great. I'm investigating how threads may starve each other in an STM implementation, and just wanted to see how many retries are triggered.